# SSH with keys not working

Tags: networking, server, ssh, authentication

I had SSH working with keys, but for some reason it stopped and I can't figure out why. I've tried reconfiguring by copying over my public key, I've tried making sure its loaded in the client, and I've even messed a little with the SSH config on the remote machine. I have ssh -v but I'm not sure what the issue is. Here is my output (with some masking)

```
[USER]@[USER]s-MBP ~ % ssh -v [USER]@[SERVER]
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/[USER]/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/[USER]/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to [SERVER] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to [SERVER]:22 as '[USER]'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:C3ILGqhuYcsr/6Vox2PCpZ05JKr/gUQI3y8RpB7Ai9U
debug1: Host '[SERVER]' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/[USER]/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: [1] touchid-mac ECDSA SHA256:D2nlwjzZ/l7+0ruNCKJ2uTaVD2kkcRghhVW1MBCcpK0 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:g5VEpqkXbAcFYTJwtLiIk+4f84Bshudqx9CXLEfo9rg
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: [1] touchid-mac ECDSA SHA256:D2nlwjzZ/l7+0ruNCKJ2uTaVD2kkcRghhVW1MBCcpK0 agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:g5VEpqkXbAcFYTJwtLiIk+4f84Bshudqx9CXLEfo9rg
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/[USER]/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: What are the access flags on the `.ssh` directory of the target id on the server (should be `drwx------`), and on  the `.ssh/authorized_keys` (should be `-rw-------`)? Also `ssh -v` shows you the client's point of view, but what happens on the server is just as important, check the `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/authlog` files.

Comment: @xenoid thank you! Auth.log told me what I need to know and I was able to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Check `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/authlog`

In my case, I had

`Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/[USER]`

Then I ran

```
chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And now it works

Comment: Which is why I asked about the access flags...

Comment: Yes- if you would like the credit feel free to add an answer I'm happy to accept it. I wasn't aware of the logs for this.

Comment: Keep the credit :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ssh-copy-id` ?
first execute this command:

```
ssh-copy-id user@server-ip
```

It will ask for your password.
Then execute the regular SSH command:

```
ssh user@server-ip
```

Comment: Yes I have done this, it is successful but still does not work.